# JavaScript iniciante em programação

Tags: javascript, string

Me ajudem a executar esse código de forma correta por favor!

> Agora que você conhece bastante JavaScript, o júri de um torneio de
>   programação nos pediu para desenvolver a função medalhaSegundoOPosto,
>   que retorna a medalha correspondente às posições, de acordo com a
>   seguinte lógica:
>
> primeiro lugar: corresponde "ouro"segundo lugar:
>   corresponde "prata"terceiro lugar: corresponde "bronze"outros lugares:
>   corresponde "Continue participando"
>
> Se executarmos a função com as seguintes posições, o resultado seria
>   assim:
>
> medalhaSegundoOPosto(1) "ouro" medalhaSegundoOPosto(2) "prata"
>   medalhaSegundoOPosto(3) "bronze" medalhaSegundoOPosto(5) "Continue
>   participando"
>
> Defina a função medalhaSegundoOPosto que recebe o posto como parâmetro
>   e retorna um texto de acordo com o parâmetro. Dica: nessa função você
>   pode usar vários if.

Escrevi o seguinte codigo:

```
var posicoes = ["continue participando", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaSegundoOPosto(numero) {
    if (numero >= posicoes.length) {
        return "continue participando";
    } {
        return posicoes[numero];
    }
}
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(1));
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(2));
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(3));
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(4));
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(9));
```

Quando executo aparece o seguintes erros:

> A execução da função medalhaSegundoOPosto(4) deve retornar 'Continue
>   participando'
>
> A execução da função medalhaSegundoOPosto(9) deve retornar 'Continue
>   participando'

Comment: `Continue participando` é diferente de `continue participando`

Comment: Copiei e colei o código que você escreveu. Executei. Funcionou perfeitamente.
Usando console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto()) com parâmetros de 0 até 9, a saída foi exatamente como a esperada: { 0 : 'continue participando', 1 : 'ouro', 2 : 'prata', ... }  e qualquer um a partir do terceiro retorna 'continue participando'.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos começar com uma explanação sobre arrays. Um array é uma variável que pode receber vários valores que são separados por índices. **Um array sempre vai começar em 0**

Podemos fazer seu código da seguinte situação:

```
var posicoes = ['Continue Participando', 'Ouro', 'Prata', 'Bronze'];
```

- Em 0 temos 'Continue Participando'
- Em 1 temos 'Ouro'
- Em 2 temos 'Prata'
- Em 3 temos 'Bronze

Então em sua função nós podemos usar o switch, que é semelhante ao IF mas você utiliza quando já sabe quais os valores vão ser declarados.

```
function medalhaSegundoOPosto(numero) {
    switch(numero) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return posicoes[numero];
        break;
        default:
            return posicoes[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Executando a função, por fim:

```
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(1));
//Ouro
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(2));
//Prata
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(3));
//Bronze
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(4));
//Continue Participando
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(0));
//Continue Participando
console.log(medalhaSegundoOPosto(10));
//Continue Participando
```

Explicando o switch:

O Switch faz a verificação da condição e retorna um valor de acordo com o que foi definido. Em seu caso fizemos um switch de numero e adicionamos os 'casos':

- Se o valor for 1 (case 1), ou 2 (case 2) ou 3 (case 3), irá retornar no console a medalha de acordo com o número enviado (posicoes[numero]).
- Se for qualquer outro número (0 ou 4 pra cima) irá chamar o coringa `default`, que é quando nenhuma condição do switch foi satisfeita. Neste caso irá exibir índice 0 de sua variável.
- Todo case precisa termina com um break, senão irá passar para a próxima instrução

E no final um exemplo onde irá exibir na tela sua função:

```js
var posicoes = ["continue participando", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaSegundoOPosto(numero) {
switch(numero) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
return posicoes[numero];
break;
default:
return posicoes[0];
break;
}
}

document.querySelector("#medalha").innerHTML =  medalhaSegundoOPosto(1);
```

```html
<div id="medalha">


</div>
```